# Expiring Django application in a particular period of time

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application that I want to deploy soon. But I want the app to display the message that the 'license expired' at a particular time (for example after 2 months or 6 months). This message should display every time the user try to login.

Please assist !

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def login(request):
    template = 'main/login.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, template)

    # POST
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if not username or not password:    # Server-side validation
        messages.error(request, 'error')
        return render(request, template)

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:    # authentication fails
        messages.error(request, 'login error')
        return render(request, template)
    
    today = datetime.date.today() 
    date = today + datetime.timedelta(month=2)
    if user.last_login > date:
        messages.error(request, 'license expired')
        return render(request, template)

    # login success
    auth_login(request, user)
    
    messages.success(request, 'login')
    return redirect('main:main')
```

calculate the date tow months from now, and compare it with the user’s last_login.